# Get the clicked object and fill the inputs in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

What I want to achieve is to be able to get all the new data on the next object that is added, also be able to click on the printed divs and get that current object to edit. I've built something, but the key logic is missing.

Problems:

1. Show current input fields
2. Be able to switch to the div (objects) and get the values in the input so I can edit

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function AddQuiz() {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(1);
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);

  function add_question() {
    const dumb = {
      id: `${Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000)}`,
      question: `${Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5)}`,
      anwser1: `${Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5)}`,
      anwser2: `${Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5)}`,
      anwser3: `${Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5)}`,
      anwser4: `${Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5)}`,
    };

    setQuestions([...questions, dumb]);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <pre>
        {' '}
        {questions.map((item) => (
          <div>
            question: {item.question} anwser1: {item.anwser1} anwser2: {item.anwser2} anwser3: {item.anwser3} anwser4:{' '}
            {item.anwser4}
          </div>
        ))}{' '}
      </pre>
      <button onClick={() => add_question()}>add dump question</button>

      <br />
      <br />
      <hr />

      {questions.length !== 0 ? (
        <form>
          <input type="text" value={questions[0].question} />
          <input type="text" value={questions[0].anwser1} />
          <input type="text" value={questions[0].anwser2} />
          <input type="text" value={questions[0].anwser3} />
          <input type="text" value={questions[0].anwser4} />
        </form>
      ) : (
        'please add some question'
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `onChange` in your `input field` and use it properly.

Here I've created a codesandbox, that you're looking for. https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-shop-cart-forked-z891d?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Nice one, closely solves the first problem, but what I really want to do is, to change the input that is currently showing the previous object for example [0], and to add many forms (inputs) like this, also what about the second problem?

Comment: you wants to get the value to input field when you click to the division (in list) ?

Comment: Yes, and to be sent to the form down, then so I can edit, then if I want I can click to another object (div) so I can edit that object and so and so

Comment: can you look into the `codesandbox` again, I've updated as you've asked. https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-shop-cart-forked-z891d?file=/src/App.js.

You can remove unncessary `input fields` as you want.
And accept my answer, please.

Comment: Yes, I will do that, but I also wondered, can I add questions not with dump data and edit questions on the same inputs?

Comment: updated sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/question-answer-z891d?file=/src/App.js

Comment: wow you really did helped me alot thanks

Comment: Can you check this one, I'm having another problem when I edit it, I've made the file together: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69985481/the-edit-is-editing-all-objects-instead-of-the-selcted-one-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
const [que1, setQue1] = useState("");

function add_question() {
    const dumb = {
      question: que1 ? que1 : Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5),
    };
    setQuestions([...questions, dumb]);
  }

<input
    type="text"
    onChange={(e) => setQue1(e.target.value)}
    defaultValue={questions[0].question}
/>
```

try:
[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-nash-kyest?file=/src/App.js)